# Viewmodel changes won't trigger event in attached behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I have a control - specifically `RadAutoCompleteBox` - and its `SelectedItems` property is bound to an `ObservableCollection<T>`. I also have a behaviour listening to `SelectionChanged` event. Whenever the user changes the selection, the event is raised - but when I use the `ObservableCollection<T>`'s `Clear` method, the event is not raised - or at least doesn't call the subscribed methods.

The way I see it, there are two options:

- I unsubscribe the method from the event somewhere that I am not aware of - I couldn't find the invocation list of the event in the debugger - so I can't be sure.
- or there is something else going on that I am not aware of.

Relevant part of the ViewModel

```
 public ObserveableCollection<TextOption> QueryPart
{
    get { return _queryPart; }
    set {
           _queryPart = value;
           OnPropertyChanged(()=> QueryPart);
        }
}

public ICommand AddQueryPart
{
     .
     .
     .
     QueryPart.Clear();
     .
     .
```

}

The relevant behaviour part

```
protected override void OnAttached
{
    .
    .
    .
    AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged +=
    AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
    .
    .
    .
}

void AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   .
   .
   .
}
```

The relevant xaml

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox SelectionMode ="Multiple" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" 
 SelectedItems= "{Binding QueryPart}"
 FlowDirection = "LeftToRight" AllowDrop = "True" >
    <i:Interaction.behaviors>
             <behaviors:FormatAutoCompleteBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors
</telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox
<RadButton Content ="+" Command="{Binding AddQueryPart}">
```

The thing is the binding works fine the selected item is cleared, it is just the event on the behavior not being called when QueryPart is called.

Comment: can we have some code here ?

Comment: The problem is the code is on a private network, and I am using a cellphone to post the question.

Comment: ok, have a look at link posted as ans, is that your same case ?

Answer (score -1):

I am aware that radAutoCompleteBox has some issues with selection or atleast it had some, can you see if this [LINK](http://www.telerik.com/forums/autocompletebox-selecteditems-binding-problem) is your issue ? as this has been reported as problem with Telerik I don't know if they have fixed it, might be useful to raise a ticket with them if its the same scenario.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be my problem - I have added some code and explanation now.